# Android app licensing. Using Titanium appcelerator instead of eclipse

Tags: android, titanium, appcelerator

I'm done creating my **Android app** with Titanium appcelerator. The last step before distribution is to have it **licensed**. The problem is that I can't find any proper documentation in regards to third party development tools and licensing. Apparently, **eclipse** is the only way to have it licensed. Has anyone used **Titanium appcelerator** and licensed their app?
Any answer, clues, hints will be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

[TiStudio](http://preview.appcelerator.com) is a standalone eclipse plugin or a full install of Aptana which uses eclipse. Have you tried that or are you working only in TiDeveloper right now?

Comment: Hey Brian thanks for answering. Yes I'm using titanium developer 1.2.2. What do you think?